# Xcode12 : how to stop showing the custom button class name on my preview

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

[My xcode preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/222Y6.png)

Hi, I am just a uikit beginner . I tried to create my own custom button , here is my code ( actually it is from online) '''

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundedButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

}
```

'''

After I create a custom button on my .xib preview , it shows the text "custom class name and !! designable " on my button.( see the link above) I have never seen this before . How to stop showing this in preview  ( it disappears in emulator )  it is really annoying